# How can I make my view height half the size?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, layout

Now I've searched a lot but nothing really is coming up that really answers my question.
How can I make my view half the size? Like for example, the android keyboard, the view only covers half the screen, how can I make my app do that? Instead of being full screen make it half in height view.

Comment: You can use a LinearLayout with 2 Views, both with a weight of **1** and a height of **0dp**. One of the two Views has its **visibility** set to **invisible**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
int mPageHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LineaLayout.LayoutParams(width, mPageHeight/2);

yourview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```